# AWS S3 Static Website isn't Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an EC2 instance from AWS. I use Route 53 to handle DNS settings. My web site works without problem.

When I want to make an upgrade on EC2 server, I want to show a message to website visitors. I set up an S3 static website for this. It is set for static website hosting. I changed DNS A record for S3 bucket.

And it doesn't work. It seems that because of the browser cache new page/site isn't fetched. All users just see that my web page isn't working for some reason. If I clear browser cache from developer console it works for me.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your bucket name identical to your domain? Without lookiing at your Route53 records, I doubt anyone would be able to point out what's the issue.

Comment: @Caldazar I found out that actually everything works but because of browser cache new page isn't shown. Do you have any idea to fix that? I will update the question.

Comment: @zarax I believe this is simply part of the cache/edge location propagation. When you make changes to your website, it may take a while for the changes to get sent down through the pipeline. Try doing a hard refresh of the page from you browser after you have uploaded changes.

Answer (score 1):

There are two caches in place which might cause issues here:

1. DNS cache
   Your system may cache DNS lookups for up to TTL of the DNS record. Use Route53 alias or set TTL to 60s.
2. Browser Cache
   Set a `Cache-Control: max-age=n` header in your document to a time you are willing to accept